# A new table for each user created

Tags: python, sql, django, database

I am using Django 3.0 and I was wondering how to create a new database table linked to the creation of each user. In a practical sense: I want an app that lets users add certain stuff to a list but each user to have a different list where they can add their stuff. How should I approach this as I can't seem to find the right documentation... Thanks a lot !!!

Comment: You add a foreign key to the records that point to the user, but the same table for all users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is too long for a comment.

Creating a new table for each user is almost never the right way to solve a problem.  Instead, you just have a `userStuff` table that maintains the lists.  It would have columns like:

- `userId`
- `stuffId`

And, if you want the stuff for a given user, just use a `where` clause.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That certainly is an easier way to do it but will it affect in any way the performance at which rate the site handles the addition and subtraction of elements?

Comment: @AlexMihoc . . . If you have an index on `userId`, then the performance will be fine.